# Destroy 'created' lifecycle method in Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component in Vue which extends from other, these extend components have a API request in the created method, but i need overwrite this, exists a way to destroy the created lifecycle method in my extended component?

Comment: Have you tried changing `key` value and forcing the component to "refresh"?, might work in this case since you can't modify the third-party component

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.